# Emotion vs Styled-Components css` prop

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I've seen that Emotion supports the following features using css prop

```
const wrapperStyle = css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

<div css={wrapperStyle}>
    ...
</div>
```

&

```
const color = 'white'

render(
  <div
    className={css`
      padding: 32px;
      font-size: 24px;
      &:hover {
        color: ${color};
      }
    `}
  >
    div content here
  </div>
)
```

.

Is there a way to do this using Styled-Components?

Also, what is the advantage of using Styled-Components over Emotion?

Comment: There is no advantage. Emotion has all the same features as styled components, has more features that styled components doesn't have, and is faster. Use Emotion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well I havent used emotion but I have been using styled-components a lot. I just looked briefly about emotion, I think the idea of the 2 is similar which is css in js. My personal taste is styled-components since the css code is outside of the markup so when reading code it is a little bit easier. So if we want to create a red button we can do like

```
const BaseButton = styled.button``;
const RedButton = styled(BaseButton)`color: red;`
```

or

```
const BaseButton == styled.button`color:${props => props.color}||'#OOO'`
const RedButton = <BaseButton color="red" />
```

However writing using emotion it seems to be easier to share css, eg a button can be styled like <button className={css`{...buttonBase, ...redButton}`}

so to answer your question, I think just pick one that you want to choose. I think they are quite similar

Comment: Emotion also has a `styled` function. You can use it in the exact same way you use Styled Components like in your first example.

Comment: ok, I havent used emotion so I dont know that. but as I said they are quite similar so just pick any and try :). I think the little advantage of emotion is to share a piece of css as I did

Comment: You can also do that with Styled Components. The advantage of Emotion is that it is faster. The APIs are virtually identical.

Comment: Ok interesting, do you have any links regarding benchmarks? When you say faster, do you mean to build faster?

Comment: I think styled components you cannot send className the same way as emotion

Comment: Benchmarks for emotion: https://medium.com/@tkh44/emotion-ad1c45c6d28b